# Manifest V3 DeclarativeNetRequest: modify headers rule is not taking effect without a tab reload

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I am migrating a chrome extension from V2 to V3. However `WebRequestBlocking` is being deprecated in V3, so to intercept and modify outgoing request headers I have to use `DeclarativeNetRequest`. The rules are supposed to intercept all outgoing network requests after filling up and submitting a form. After filling the form the url is also modified to navigate to that page, but the headers are not being added unless a tab reload is forced to happen.

I have tried to apply the rules based on a listener on tab being updated, from `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. I have also tried adding the listener to `chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` and `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders`. But none of these solutions have applied the rules without a tab reload.

This is the V3 code for backgroud.ts that I am using to trigger the action when the form is submitted.

```
// Handle submission of new data
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {

const tabId = sender?.tab?.id ?? message.tabId;
const tab = await chrome.tabs.get(tabId!);

switch (message.type) {
    case 'submit':
        const options = await getOptions();
        
        newUrl.searchParams.set('value', message.value);

        // If the new Url would be the same as the old URL, don't update the tab
        if (newUrl.toString() === tab.url) {
            return;
        }
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: newUrl.toString()}, (r) => {
            console.log('updated tab', r);
        });
        break;
    case 'log':
        console.log(`${message.message}:`, message);
        break;
}
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
console.log('On Tab Updated');
if (tab.status !== 'loading') {
    return;
}
// Get the declarative net request rules for this session
const allRules = await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getSessionRules();

// Get the current rules for this tab
const currentRulesForTab = allRules.filter((rule) => {
    return rule.condition?.tabIds?.includes(tabId);
});

if (
    condition
) {
    const newRulesForTab = await getRules();

    if (!currentRulesForTab.length) { 
        await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            type: 'log',
            message: 'Initializing session rules for this tab',
            rules: newRulesForTab
        });
        await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
            addRules: newRulesForTab
        });
        // Reload this tab again
        await chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);
    } else { 
        if (currentRules !== newRules) {
            // Send chrome message to this tab to log that the tab is being updated
            await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                type: 'log',
                message: 'Updating session rules for this tab',
                rules: newRulesForTab
            });
            await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
                removeRuleIds: currentRulesForTab.map((rule) => rule.id),
                addRules: newRulesForTab
            });
            // Reload this tab again
            await chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);
        }
    }
} else { 
    if (currentRulesForTab.length) {
        // Send chrome message to this tab to log that the tab is being updated
        await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            type: 'log',
            message: 'Removing session rules for this tab',
            rules: currentRulesForTab
        });
        await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
            removeRuleIds: currentRulesForTab.map((rule) => rule.id)
        });
        // Reload this tab again
        await chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Add the old MV2 code and the new MV3 code to the question.

Comment: Declarative rules are applied asynchronously after you call updateSessionRules, which you do after the tab has already started loading, meaning only the next load will be affected. You must prepare all the rules beforehand. It may be impossible depending on how the logic is determined.